# try with resource call for code in try block

Tags: java

```
ZipFile zipFile = null;
InputStreamReader fileReader = null;
CSVParser csvReportParser = null;
List<CSVRecord> reportRecord = null;

try
{
  zipFile = new ZipFile(reportPath);
  Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
  /** Assuming there is only one file in zip */
  ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
  InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
  fileReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, CHARSET_NAME);
  csvReportParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat);
  reportRecord = csvReportParser.getRecords();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  LOG.error("File not found at path" + reportPath, e);
  throw new ClientConsoleException(e);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  LOG.error("Error in reading file at path" + reportPath, e);
  throw new ClientConsoleException(e);
}
finally
{
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(csvReportParser);
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileReader);
  try
  {
    if (zipFile != null)
      zipFile.close();
  }
  catch (final IOException e)
  {
    LOG.error("Cannot close zip file" + reportPath, e);
  }
}

return reportRecord;
```

I want to use try with resource in the above code. Here already try block is there and here only 3 classes can be written in the try with resource block.
Can you please help me to put in a correct way above code in try with resource ?

Comment: What do you mean by "only 3 classes can be written in the block"? Please exactly explain what happens / what is undesired, and what you want to achieve instead.

Comment: The resources(classes) which implement the Closeable can only be written inside the try with resources right. So here in this method, 3 classes can be written in the try resources list. But I coudnt succeed in converting the below method or resources in try resources list.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html yet?

Answer (score 0):

To put a resource into a try-with-resource statement, wrap it in brackets as shown below:

```
public static List<CSVRecord> example() {
    CSVParser csvReportParser = null;
    List<CSVRecord> reportRecord = new ArrayList<>();
    String reportPath = "bla";

    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(reportPath)) {
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

        try (InputStreamReader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, CHARSET_NAME)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(csvReportParser);
    }

    return reportRecord;
}
```

Because I don't know what `CSVParser` is, I left it as is. If it implements the `Closable` interface, then `CSVParser` can be included inside a try-with-resources statement as well:

```
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(reportPath);
     CSVParser  csvReportParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFormat)) {
    ...
}
```